# Stemming function for text2vec

Tags: r, text2vec

I am using text2vec in R and having difficulty writing a stemming function that works with the itoken function in the text2vec package. The text2vec documentation suggests this stemming function:

```
stem_tokenizer1 =function(x) {
  word_tokenizer(x) %>% lapply(SnowballC::wordStem(language='en'))
 }
```

However, this function does not work. This is the code I ran (borrowed from previous stackoverflow answers):

```
library(text2vec)
library(data.table)
library(SnowballC)
data("movie_review")
train_rows = 1:1000
prepr = tolower
stem_tokenizer1 =function(x) {
  word_tokenizer(x) %>% lapply(SnowballC::wordStem(language='en'))
 }
tok = stem_tokenizer1
it <- itoken(movie_review$review[train_rows], prepr, tok, ids = movie_review$id[train_rows])
```

This is the error it produces:

**Error in { : argument "words" is missing, with no default**

I believe the issue is that wordStem needs a character vector, but word_tokenizer produces a list of character vectors.

```
mr<-movie_review$review[1]
stem_mr1<-stem_tokenizer1(mr)
```

**Error in SnowballC::wordStem(language = "en") : 
  argument "words" is missing, with no default**

To fix this issue, I wrote this stemming function:

```
stem_tokenizer2 = function(x)  {
  list(unlist(word_tokenizer(x)) %>% SnowballC::wordStem(language='en') )
}
```

However, this function does not work with the create_vocabulary function.

```
data("movie_review")
train_rows = 1:1000
prepr = tolower
stem_tokenizer2 = function(x)  {
  list(unlist(word_tokenizer(x)) %>% SnowballC::wordStem(language='en') )
}
tok = stem_tokenizer2
it <- itoken(movie_review$review[train_rows], prepr, tok, ids = movie_review$id[train_rows])
v <- create_vocabulary(it) %>% prune_vocabulary(term_count_min = 5)
```

No error, but when you look at the document count,  the number of documents is different than the 1000 in the data, and so you cannot create a document term matrix or run an LDA.

```
v$document_count
```

**[1] 10**

This code:

```
dtm_train <- create_dtm(it, vectorizer)
dtm_train
```

Producess this error:

**10 x 3809 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
Error in validObject(x) : 
  invalid class “dgCMatrix” object: length(Dimnames[1]) differs from Dim[1] which is 10**

My questions are: is there something wrong with the function I wrote, and why would the function I wrote produce this error with create_vocabulary? I suspect it is a problem with the format of the output of my function, but it looks identical to the word_tokenizer function's output format, and that works fine with itoken and create_vocabulary:

```
mr<-movie_review$review[1]
word_mr<-word_tokenizer(mr)
stem_mr<-stem_tokenizer2(mr)
str(word_mr)
str(stem_mr)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for using `text2vec` and reporting the problem.
There is a mistake in docs (can you point me where I put this example, so I can fix it?).
Stem tokenizer should look like:

```
stem_tokenizer1 =function(x) {
  word_tokenizer(x) %>% lapply( function(x) SnowballC::wordStem(x, language="en"))
 }
```

Logic is following:

1. It take character vector and tokenize it. Output is list of
   character vectors (each element of list = character vector is a document).
2. Then we apply stemming on each element of list (`wordStem` can be applied on character vector)

So there was my syntax mistake for `lapply` in example you followed. Mb it will be more clear if we rewrite it without `%>%` operator in plain R so it will look like:

```
stem_tokenizer1 =function(x) {
  tokens = word_tokenizer(x)
  lapply(tokens, SnowballC::wordStem, language="en")
}
```

I will also explain why you are receiving 10 docs instead of 1000. By default `text2vec::itoken` split data into 10 chunks (this can be adjusted in `itoken` function) and process it chunk by chunk. 
So when you are applying `unlist` on each chunk you are actually recursively unlist 100 documents and creating 1 character vector.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I ran the code and it has the document count at 30, is this the same issue you mentioned with creating 1 character vector? code:   `data("movie_review")
train_rows = 1:1000
prepr = tolower
stem_tokenizer1 =function(x) {
  word_tokenizer %>% lapply( function(x) SnowballC::wordStem(x, language="en"))
 }
tok = stem_tokenizer1
it <- itoken(movie_review$review[train_rows], prepr, tok, ids = movie_review$id[train_rows])
v <- create_vocabulary(it) %>% prune_vocabulary(term_count_min = 5)
v$document_count`

Comment: My bad. Missed x in `word_tokenizer(x)`, see updated answer.